# I have a question about .map to bring elements in the array into an array with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to bring the elements in an array into other arrays in the array. I have now read that `.map` works well and have found `newArrayA` as an example. Can't I just leave out the dots and just do it as in `newArrayB`? Does anyone have anything else to read? I can find almost nothing on this example. Is there anything that speaks against `newArrayB`?

```js
let test = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']; // to [ [ 'A' ], [ 'B' ], [ 'C' ], [ 'D' ] ]

newArrayA = test.map((x) => [...x]);
newArrayB = test.map((x) => [x]);

console.log(newArrayA);
console.log(newArrayB);
```

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do, for example, what if you had a string in test with two or more characters? Then the two maps above will produce different results. But for your example above, the second is fine

Comment: Thank you, I had only tried with one character. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the difference by increasing the length of one of the strings - you get different results when you use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) vs simply using the value at an index - just run this example:

```js
let test = ['ABCDE', 'B'];  

newArrayA = test.map((x) => [...x]);
newArrayB = test.map((x) => [x]);

console.log(newArrayA);
console.log(newArrayB);
```